# Using Gaussian mixture model for labelled and unlabelled data in scikit learn?

Tags: machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, scikits, expectation-maximization

I have data out of which some of it is labelled and some of it is not labelled. 
I need to apply Expectation maximization algorithm.
Is it possible to apply it in Sci-kit learn? Any example of labelled + unlabelled instances would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Not really. Scikit-learn provides more black-box algorithms. GMMs are usually not meant as supervised models.
Writing the EM yourself should be pretty straight-forward, though.
You could try to hack the sklearn implementation, but writing your own might be simpler in this case.

Comment: OP's question is bit vague, but what's wrong with using scikits [Gaussian mixture model](http://scikit-learn.org/0.5/modules/gmm.html)?  OP's labeled data is, I assume, his training data, and implement the learned model on the unlabeled examples?

Comment: the GMM module is unsupervised and doesn't take any labels in fitting.

Comment: But assuming you are not missing any classes in your labeled data, you then know how many states to train the model, right?

Comment: Yes but you are not making use of the label information.

Comment: You could actually fit a GMM using fixed indicators together with data without indicators to learn a model. That is what I thought op was asking.

Comment: Ok sure.. Thanks ..  E-M implementation seems straightforward.